# import module error python3 xubuntu 19.04

Tags: python-3.x, import, pygame, geany

When importing PyGame using the interpreter it is successful. Using Geany it is not.

[image: enter description]
shows the error.

I have tried editing the shebang, renaming the file. making sure the PATH and version were correct, and that there were no missing Geany plugins.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
```

Error in Geany:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "moduleerror.py", line 3, in <module>
    import pygame
ImportError: No module named pygame
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Adding links of what you tried usually doesn't help; we need to see what you actually tried, so [edit] your question and include all the source code here as text as a [mcve]. Quick guess -- did you install that pygame module?

Comment: yes, using pip3 install and sudo. that was common in the threads i read. i edited the post

Comment: you have installed pygame for python3 and Geany is probably using Python2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went into Build >> Set Build Commands and under Execute commands changed

python "%f"

to

python3 "%f"